# How to set text color for particular word in a sentence?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my response :

```
     Upto 1Feet $2
     After 3Feet $0.025
```

In this above response, I need to set green color for $2 and $0.025. Other text contains black color.

This is my xml Code,

```
          <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/book_cardview_estimate_layout_driver"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/book_cardview_area_layout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/estimate_layout_driver"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <com.mylibrary.widgets.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/estimate_driver_text_upto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                        android:text="Upto "
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <com.mylibrary.widgets.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/estimate_driver_text_after"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/estimate_driver_text_upto"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:text="After"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is java Code,

```
    Tv_estimate_driver_text_upto.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.upto) + " " + min_feet + getResources().getString(R.string.feet) + " " + sCurrencySymbol + min_fare);


  Tv_estimate_driver_text_after.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.after) + " " + after_per_feet + getResources().getString(R.string.feet) + " " + sCurrencySymbol + after_per_multi);
```

Explanation :

```
getResources().getString(R.string.upto)  = upto text,

min_feet  = 1 (its comes from json response),

getResources().getString(R.string.feet) = feet,

sCurrencySymbol  = $ (this comes from json response),

min_fare = 2 (some amount , comes from json response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your String as Html such as

`<b><font color=#FF0000>$2</font></b>` and setText with Html.fromHtml()

such as

```
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.upto) + " " + min_feet +
     getResources().getString(R.string.feet) + 
" <font color=#00FF00>" + sCurrencySymbol + min_fare + "</font></b>"));
```

Comment: Its Working For me. Thank You @slee

Comment: @Ana if something works for you, then accept the answer please.

Comment: Tv_estimate_driver_text_upto.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.upto) + " " + min_feet + getResources().getString(R.string.feet) + " " + " <font color=#008A07>" + sCurrencySymbol + min_fare + "</font></b>"));
                Tv_estimate_driver_text_after.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.after) + " " + after_per_feet + getResources().getString(R.string.feet) + " " +" <font color=#008A07>" +sCurrencySymbol + after_per_multi+ "</font></b>"));

Answer (score 2):

Using [Spans](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html) you can change style of part of Sentence.

Example :

```
// text1 for different color
text1 = "Upto 1Feet $";

// text 2 in different color
            String text2 = min_fare;

            span1 = new SpannableString(text1);
// optional if you want to change text size
            span1.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize1), 0, text1.length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

// code for changing color of string 1
            span1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)), 0,
                    text1.length(), 0);
            // do same for string two and concat both span 
            CharSequence finalText = TextUtils.concat(span1, span2);

           txtEventType.setText(finalText);
```

**EDIT**

> void setSpan (Object what, 
>                   int start, 
>                   int end, 
>                   int flags)
>
> Object what : What to apply ForegroundColorSpan / AbsoluteSizeSpan , start : start of string,end : end of string , flags : [Flag of Spanned](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html)

Comment: Spannable wordStr = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.upto) + " " + min_feet + getResources().getString(R.string.feet) + " " + sCurrencySymbol + min_fare); wordStr.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green)), 9, 0, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); Tv_estimate_driver_text_upto.setText(wordStr);

Comment: Having doubt in this, I set green color only for currencysymbol and min_fare value. so i set start value is 9 and what i set the end value. because minfare contains value . so min_fare length varies from json response

Comment: I found a single line code . Got my answer !!!                     wordStr.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green)), 10, wordStr.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);